# Как сделать, чтобы цикл работал определённое время?

Tags: циклы

Есть вещественное t (от 1 до 10), время в минутах. В цикле от 1 до 100500 (с 4 присваиваниями внутри), надо сделать задержку sleep(). Какая величина параметра в миллисекундах должна быть в sleep(), для того, чтобы цикл продлился ровно t минут?

Comment: @Ваня Уточните язык программирования.

Answer (score 3):

Во время выполнения цикла проверять, сколько он длится, допустим **n**, после выполнения цикла сделать задержку **t-n** единиц времени, если же указанное время **t** меньше времени выполнения цикла, прервать его во время вышеописанной проверки.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще говоря, о точности в Windows говорить нельзя. Функция Sleep() погружает поток в "сон" на заданный интервал, но выйти из него он может и позднее (это как планировщик "решит"). Функция Win32 API GetTickCount() или ее эквивалент для быстрых итераций может не подойти (данная функция возвращает время прошедшее со старта Windows в ms). Если тело цикла исполняется очень быстро можно рекомендовать QueryPerformanceFrequency/QueryPerformanceCounter